# Produce MD5 or SHA1 hash code to long (64 bits)

Tags: algorithm, hash, cryptography, md5, sha1

I need to compute a hash code of a string and store it into a 'long' variable.

MD5 and SHA1 produce hash codes which are longer than 64 bits (MD5 - 128 bits, SHA1 - 160 bit).

Ideas any one?

Cheers,

Doron

Comment: One idea: don't. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @larsmans Likely because they want to use it as a non-cryptographic hash as a weak check to make sure they're not generating multiple of the same thing, and don't want to store a lot of hexadecimal strings of the 128-bit hashes.

Comment: This is a great approach for like, a synthetic clustering key (when you don't want to store a long user id) or for storing file hashes in a database-driver file system. Absolutely accelerates duplicate detection by storing short hashes for the files. I would even store series of hashes based on like first N bytes of file and another hash for last N bytes of file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can truncate the hash and use just the first 64 bits. The hash will be somewhat less strong, but the first 64 bits are still extremely likely to be unique.

For most uses of a hash this is both a common and perfectly acceptable practice.

You can also store the complete hash in two 64-bit integers.

Comment: Note that if security is important, MD5 is considered a very poor choice. It is still fine for storing hashes of non-secret data though.

Comment: I disagree that "For most uses of a hash this is both a common and perfectly acceptable practice.". Secure hashes are frequently used in situations where a 64 bit hash is unacceptable for security or collision-rate reasons.

Comment: @NickJohnson: Sorry about the late reply (what's a few years?). True, secure hashes should be more than 64 bits, among other things. Note that I said "for MOST uses of a hash" -- secure hashes are, in my experience, a drop in the bucket when many basic data structures use a hash for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The [FNV Hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) is pretty easy to implement.  We extended it to 64 bits and it works very well.  Using it is much faster than computing MD5 or SHA1 and then truncating the result.  However, we don't depend on it for cryptographic functions--just for hash tables and such.

More information on FNV, with source code and detailed explanations: http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this (Java):

```
public class SimpleLongHash {
    final MessageDigest md;
    //
    public SimpleLongHash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    }
    //
    public long hash(final String str) {
        return hash(str.getBytes());
    }
    public long hash(final byte[] buf) {
        md.reset();
        final byte[] digest = md.digest(buf);
        return (getLong(digest, 0) ^ getLong(digest, 8));
    }
    //
    private static final long getLong(final byte[] array, final int offset) {
        long value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            value = ((value << 8) | (array[offset+i] & 0xFF));
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What would be the probability for a collision as a result of a XOR between the first 64 bits and the last 64 bits?

Answer (score 0):

XOR the bits together? E.g. for MD5, bits 0-63 XOR bits 64-127, voila, 64 bits. This will give you a weaker hash, check if that's acceptable for you.

(also, unless your environment is *extremely* constrained - e.g. embedded devices - there's a question of "why do you *need* to shorten it?")

Comment: There's no need to XOR bits together - in a secure hash, any subset will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also play with various hash algorithms with FooBabel [Hasher](http://www.foobabel.com/apps/cs?name=Hasher)

Comment: Link points to a website which no longer exists